# Getting notifications from a Website inside an iframe to show in main app

Tags: iframe, notifications

because this is a fairly open questin, I need to give some context first:
In an educational institution we are using certain web services for different tasks. Because this is confusing for some colleagues and students, we developed a very simple PWA as "frontend wrapper" for our main services. The services are loaded in iframes and so are displayed under a convenient to use GUI.
One of the integrated services is a messaging client (remote site, not under our control but provided by an external hoster), which integrates nicely with the frontend, but the notifications (e. g. when new messages arrive) are not displayed - which is understandable, because the iframe context is of course regulated by X-Frame-Options and other security messures (we are mainly using Chrome to display the PWA).
My question is: Is there any way I could get notifications from this specific iframe to show in the browser oder system context - or another approach that would fit the purpose? Any help or idea would be much appreciated!

We tried:

- adding a custom notification management (and load it via service worker):

```
    self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
      var remoteSiteURL = 'https://app.schul.cloud';
    
      if (event.data && event.data.json && event.data.json.origin === remoteSiteURL) {
        var options = {
          body: event.data.json.body,
          icon: 'icon.png',
          // ...
        };

        event.waitUntil(
          self.registration.showNotification('Benachrichtigung von Remote-Site', options)
        );
      }
    });
```

- Manualy set the browser permissions for generating notifications for both the main app and the messaging service in the irame

Comment: "the notifications (e. g. when new messages arrive) are not displayed"

Can you give more details about how these notifications work, and what goes wrong when they're coming from the iframed site? Are they native browser notifications, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! They are native browser notifications. When I open the remote site directly in a browser, they are displayed correctly. Inside iframed context they are not.